# How to upload to a specific folder in the Google Drive GoogleAPIs v3 in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I'm want to upload images to a specific folder.

This is the function i'm using right now to upload my files, it uploads them the to main folder:

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as driveV3;

Future upload(File file) async {
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = driveV3.DriveApi(client);
    var response = await drive.files.create(
        driveV3.File()..name = p.basename(file.absolute.path),
        uploadMedia: driveV3.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync())
        );
}
```

What i want is a way to upload ALWAYS to a folder that can be created at the first time or something like that. what do i need to modify in the above function so i can specify a folder name `EX: MyFolder` and always uploads to it?

Answer (score 0):

### You are looking for the `parents` of the `File` class

This property takes a list of String. These strings are the folders you want to upload the file to. As it seems, a file can be uploaded in multiple folders.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Future upload(File file) async {
  var client = await getHttpClient();
  var drive = driveV3.DriveApi(client);
  file.parents = ["folder_id"];
  var response = await drive.files.create(
      driveV3.File()..name = p.basename(file.absolute.path),
      uploadMedia: driveV3.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync())
  );
}
```

On the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.drive.v3/File/parents.html) I quote:

> The IDs of the parent folders which contain the file. If not specified
>   as part of a create request, the file will be placed directly in the
>   user's My Drive folder. If not specified as part of a copy request,
>   the file will inherit any discoverable parents of the source file.
>   Update requests must use the addParents and removeParents parameters
>   to modify the parents list.

Comment: but how do i get that `folder_id`?

Comment: Try create the folder manually in Google drive and the id should be the last part of the url for example:  `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1cYGoIfI1ZkJxtuvasdfW4J9gVT_bNlXeKQ` it should be `1cYGoIfI1ZkJxtuvasdfW4J9gVT_bNlXeKQ`

Comment: is there a way to do that in the function that uploads the file. because it's not logic to ask users of your app to make a folder and copy the id then past it in a form or something like that. the practical approach is to do it programmatically, and store all files that belong to this app to a folder with the app name